# Regular expression conflict

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this regex code:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !/login([/]{0,1}) [NC]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !/search/([/]{0,1}) [NC]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !/search/([^.]+)([/]{0,1}) [NC]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ products.php/$1/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([^.]+)/?$ products.php/$1/$2/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^login([/]{0,1})?$ login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search([/]{0,1})?$ search.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^.]+)/?$ search.php/$1/ [NC,L]
```

The problem is when i go to site/search/asdf regex redirects me to products.php file.
How can i fix this?

Comment: `[/]{0,1}` can be simplified to `/?`

Comment: yes the last character can be / or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from resorting your regexes, there's no need for the `{0,1}`:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^.]+)/?$ search.php/$1/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search(/?)?$ search.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^login(/?)?$ login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([^.]+)/?$ products.php/$1/$2/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ products.php/$1/ [NC,L]
```

`[/]{0,1}` is exactly the same as `/?`. The `?` means: "Zero or one of the preceding element."

Comment: i thought [/]{0,1} must be added thank you now the code is more clean and more understandful :).Sorry for not voting you up i need 15 Reputations :P.

Comment: @AntonioPapa: Thanks for accepting this answer. You'll get the 15 rep some time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just change the order of your `RewriteRule`'s from most-to-least specific:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^.]+)/?$ search.php/$1/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search([/]{0,1})?$ search.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^login([/]{0,1})?$ login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([^.]+)/?$ products.php/$1/$2/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ products.php/$1/ [NC,L]
```